# Magento 2.3.2 - Custom attribute address deleted when click on Pay with paypal express checkout

Tags: php, paypal, custom-attributes, magento-2.0

I'm custom attribute address on quote_address and sales_order_address (fiscal_code,fiscal_company,fiscal_sdi all in type text).

When I pay with stripe the attribute is not deleted but when I pay with paypal the attributes in quote_address are deleted as soon as I access the paypal page.

If I pay with braintree with paypal all right.

What's wrong with the paypal module or I have to set up some checkout sessions in module custom attribute?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have created a new custom attribute please check if it's getting set during the action you are performing.

You can log the data during the actions you are performing to check the actual reason.